# Insert additional information in the sendSweetAlert in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to include the industries that will be excluded in my code message alert. Is this possible to do? In the executable code below I made an "output$ind" that shows the industries that will be excluded. However, I would like to insert this information into the message alert that I created as well.

```
library(shiny)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)

function.cl<-function(df){

  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Industries = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.4,-23.5), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.8, -49.3, -49.4, -49.8, -49.6,-49.3,-49.1), 
                     Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))


  coordinates<-subset(df,select=c("Latitude","Longitude")) 
  d<-distm(coordinates[,2:1]) 
  diag(d)<-1000000 
  min_distancia<-as.matrix(apply(d,MARGIN=2,FUN=min))
  limite<-mean(min_distancia)+sd(min_distancia) 


  search_vec <- function(mat, vec, dim = 1, tol = 1e-7, fun = all)
  which(apply(mat, dim, function(x) fun((x - vec) > tol)))
  ind_exclude<-search_vec(min_distancia,limite,fun=any)
  if(is_empty(ind_exclude)==FALSE){
  for (i in 1:dim(as.array(ind_exclude))){
  df<-subset(df,Industries!=ind_exclude[i])}}


   return(list(
    "IND" =  ind_exclude
  ))

}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(

                          h4("The excluded industries are:"),
                          tableOutput("ind"),

                          selectInput("filter1", h3("Select farms"),
                                      choices = list("All farms" = 1, 
                                                     "Exclude farms" = 2),
                                      selected = 1),


                          ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel())))))  

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df)
  })

  output$ind <- renderTable({
    IND <- ((Modelcl()[[1]]))
  })

  observe({
    if(input$filter1 == 2){
      sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "Information!",
        btn_labels = c("Yes", "No"),
        text = tags$div(h5("The industries that need to exclude are:"), 

        ),

        type = "info"
      )
    }
  })


  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, sure. You can just include the same reactive Value that you used for the table, cant you?

```
sendSweetAlert(
  session = session,
  title = "Information!",
  btn_labels = c("Yes", "No"),
  text = tags$div(h5("The industries that need to exclude are:", 
                     # just include the same information here
                     paste(Modelcl()[[1]], collapse = ", "))

  ),
  type = "info"
)
```

Comment: Please, could you look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61988758/functionality-for-the-confirm-button-that-confirmsweetalert-generates-in-shiny